# Regex braincramp - match "foreign" but not "foreign key"

Tags: c#, regex

Still getting used to lookarounds in regex, but can't seem to get

```
\b(?>! key)foreign\b
```

To be the right solution?
I'm trying to find all instances of the word foreign in some text, but NOT foreign key or foreignkey.

Comment: A [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is implemented with simply `?!`, not `?>!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookahead needs to be after `foreign` (and you don't need the `>`):

```
\bforeign(?! key)\b
```

The word boundary will handle the `foreignkey` case.

Comment: Interestingly, `?>!` compiles fine: http://www.rubular.com/r/yav5bOgzZc.  But I can't find any documentation on what it means?

Comment: Marked for explanation. thank you. @mellamokb the < > are supposed to indicate look forward or look behind.

Comment: @kpcrash: Intuitively it would seem so.  However, if you look [at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx), there is no reference to `(?>` as a valid pattern.  The correct pattern is `(?<=` or `(?<!` for lookbehind and `(?=` or `(?!` for lookahead

Comment: @mellamokb `(?> ... )` is an "[atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)." The exclamation point is taken as a literal character in this case.

Answer (score 2):

How about: `\bforeign(?!\s?key)\b`

Example: http://regexr.com?343k9